# A better way than printk() to leave a kernel module log?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am using[`printk()`](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch18lev1sec3) to leave a log message of a kernel module. I've modified [`ath9k_htc`](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath9k_htc) WLAN card module to leave a log message whenever a WLAN card transmits or receives a data or an acknowledgement frame. A log meesage contains a frame type and clock cycles.

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG "MyModule: DATA at %llu\n", get_ccnt());
```

where `get_ccnt()` is:

```
static __inline__ long long int get_ccnt(void)
{
#if defined(__i386__)
    long long int x;
    __asm__ volatile (".byte 0x0f, 0x31" : "=A" (x));
    return x;

#elif defined(__x86_64__)
    unsigned int hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ( (long long int)lo)|( ((long long int)hi)<<32 );

#endif
}
```

What I concern is, frames are transmitted and received very frequently. But I think `printk()` cannot be executed and finished as fast as frames are transmitted and received.

Before I decided to use `prinkt()`, I have though about using `message queue` or `signal`. But, I've given up using them because they are not easy to use in a kernel module or I have little knowledge about it.

(Yes, I want to pass a frame type and clock cycles from a kernel module to a userspace app. As I am using `printk()`, I read a log message with the following:)

```
FILE *fp = popen("dmesg | grep MyModule");
char linebuff[512];
while (fgets(linebuff, 512, fp) != NULL) {
    do_something();
}
```

So, is it not good to use `printk()` to pass a message from a kernel module to a userspace app when a messagecontains time-critical data?

One trivial question is, calling `get_ccnt()` function makes measurements of clock cycles inaccurate? I don't think so because it is an `__inline__` function...

Comment: Canonical way to go is debugfs.

Comment: i've used a netlink libnl library http://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/ to send and recv data between a user space app and a kernel module, plus some notifications from a kernel module, it is easy to implement

Comment: @sim, do you mean `libnl` can measure a time when frames are tx'ed or rx'ed? Or do you just mean that it has a capability of triggerint data transmission and reception?

Comment: @Jeon it's a lib to simplify usage of netlink protocol, which main goal is to communicate between user space and kernel space, with netlink you can create events in your kernel module and subscribe your userspace app for them

Comment: @sim, Oh, until now I understand `libnl` is a library for communication (e.g. ethernet, wifi...). I learn something new here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `printk()` for heavy loaded task usually a bad idea. Either *trace points*, or *perf* are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you're trying to do, but the fact that you want to write code to run `dmesg` and `grep` its contents implies that this is not just for debugging. In that case, `printk` is not the right solution. You should use the device interface to pass information from your module to user-space. That's what it's for. Then your user-space code can just open `/dev/mydevice` and read data from it.

`printk` is for debugging and diagnostics, not for ordinary communication between kernel- and user-space. You will totally overwhelm the `printk` buffer if there is any significant amount of network traffic.

Use of the timestamp counter is fine for debugging, but is generally ill-suited for stable long-term time measurements (among others, processor frequencies vary, and multiple processors might not be synchronized). You're better off using `ktime_get` or `do_gettimeofday` or one of the other kernel time interfaces.